# How to enable remoteproc and rpmsg in Google Coral Dev Board (NXP i.MX 8M)

Tags: cortex-m, google-coral, imx8, mendel-os

Hi I'm using a Google coral with NXP i.MX 8M and I'm trying to enable communication between Cortex-A53 and Cortex M4F. For that I need the remoteproc and rpmsg.
So I already flashed the Mendel OS on the board. (https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/)
Then I followed the exampled to enable the CORTEX M4F:
https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/demo_apps/hello_world_tflite/
I was able to compile, and run the example with sucess on Cortex M4F.

Then I tried to follow the example to enable multicore: https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/multicore_examples/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos/readme.txt*https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/multicore_examples/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos/readme.txt

I was able to compile the bin file on the example and "flash" it on the Cortex-M4F using the same method as hello world:

```
On the device:
sudo cp hello_world_tflite.bin /boot
cd /boot
sudo ln -sf hello_world_tflite.bin m4_fw.bin

On the device, in u-boot:
setenv m4enabled 1
saveenv
boot
```

But no output is visible...
How do I enable the remoteproc on Mendel side?
What is missing?

I want to be able to control the cortex m4 with mendel-os.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the shared memory address in the Linux device tree matches the address on the M4 side.